# HTML/CSS border shadow inside object

Tags: css, border, shadow

I'm looking for a way to make list having borders with solid shadows, looking just like a second border without using images for borders as it would be used with changing text, meaning width also changes.

Result I'm aiming for would be:

[image: Aimed result]

But without adding second object with negative z-index and complicating everything with scripts for width change and etc. only result I am getting is

[image: Result with coding]

CSS code used would be quite simple

```
li {
  padding: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #718496;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(68, 150, 210, 0.5);
          box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(68, 150, 210, 0.5);
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 18px;
}
```

*box with icon only is just for showcasing effect I'm after, not the only box I need it for.

Is there any possibility to achieve this effect without second object with border under it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`border-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) can take up to 6 arguments (see the [mdn doc #values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow#Values) for a complete definition):

- offset-x: *horizontal  offset*
- offset-y: *vertical offset*
- blur-radius: *blur effect of the outside of the shadow*
- spread-radius: *solid color (without blur) thickness*
- color: *no need for a description here* :)
- inset: (facultative) *if you want your shadow to go inside your block*

In order to achieve what you want, you need to use the `blur-radius` & `spread-radius` instead of the `offset-xy` you are currently using.

Here's an exemple:

```css
div{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #aaf;
}

#id1{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #55f;
}

#id2{
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 15px #55f;
}

#id3{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #55f;
}

#id4{
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #55f; /* here's what you want */
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">sharp thick border without blur</div>

<div id="id2">thick border with blur</div>

<div id="id3">thin border without blur</div>

<div id="id4">thin border with blur</div>
```

---

**Edit:** didn't saw what you want because of crappy colors on my screen.

Here's the snippet (I made the borders 3px wide to make people clearly see what your are talking about).

```css
*{
  background-color: #ddd;
}

div{
  margin: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #aaf;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 0 0 #00a,
              3px 3px 0 0 #00a inset;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1"></div>
```

Comment: Not really what I would be aiming for. I'm aiming for a solid 1px shadow, like border, both inset and not at the same time with offset-xy being at 1px for both.

Comment: Wow sorry I didn't saw the thin pixel border :o - will edit my post

Comment: Thanks for your time. For as long as I have used box-shadow in css, never really realized that 2 values could be used at once.

Comment: Yes, it is inconvenient that the mdn doc does not contain this kind of information (as well as all one-liners in general).

Comment: For the past hour I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure everything out without realizing that, even thinking about adding another object with js trickery to match width and height for second border, now I can finally move on with other stuff.